# What's the difference between `ttl` and `time_to_live` property in FCM message for android push?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the FCM document, there are two properties in the message named `ttl` and `time_to_live`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options.html#ttl
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options.html#lifetime

It looks like the same feature.

I want to set the message lifespan.

Which property should I use?

Answer (score 4):

They are used for the same purpose -- setting the lifespan of the payload.

Difference is that [`ttl` is the *key* for FCM v1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/#androidconfig) while [`time_to_live` is for FCM Legacy](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json).